# Refactoring for beginners

Tags: php, codeigniter, refactoring

So I have built a system and now I am tidying up. Im using Codeigniter MVC framework and PHP Storm, I have a huge chunk of maths in my view. see bellow.

```
 foreach ($records as $row) :

            $join_date = $row->start_date;
            $date1 = new DateTime('now');
            $date2 = new DateTime($join_date);

            $p = $row->start_amount;
            $i = $row->interest;
            $c = 12; // compound frequency set to monthly
            $n = ((int)$date1->diff($date2)->format("%m")) / 12;
            $r = $row->monthly_deposits;
            $x = $i / $c;
            $y = pow((1 + $x), ($n * $c));
            $Total_balance = $p * $y + ($r * (1 + $x) * ($y - 1) / $x);

            $remain = 365 - $date1->diff($date2)->format("%a days");

            $Total_Deposits = ($row->monthly_deposits * (int)$date1->diff($date2)->format("%m")) + $row->start_amount;
            $Total_Int = $Total_balance - $Total_Deposits;

            $originalDate = $row->start_date;
            $newDate = date("jS \of F Y", strtotime($originalDate));

            // Add field values to get row total
            $rowTotal = $Total_balance;

            // Add row total to grand total
            $grandTotal += $rowTotal;
            ?>
```

I need it so I can call the variables in my code and it needs to be within the loop.

Whats the best way to do this, show I put the maths in a model and the something like `this>model>modelname` within the loop ?

Thanks guys, the code works fine just not sure on the best way to keep it tidy.

Comment: Why not just put all of that code directly into a function in the model, call that function in the controller, and send the data it returned directly to the view. The view shouldn't have that much business logic in it.

Comment: Ahh thats along the lines i was thinking, thank you. i will try

Comment: plus one for refactoring to a model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views are meant basically to display what you have already computed in your controllers. Take this as a general rule (that doesn't mean you can't compute anything on your models or views if needed).

To keep the code clean and meaningful, I would do the following:

**Model**

```
class Random_model extends CI_Model {
    function get_records() {
        // access the database and return the rows you need
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
function whatever() {
    $data = array(
        'first_result' => '',
        'second_result' => ''
    );

    $this->load->model('random_model');
    $records = $this->random_model->get_records();
    foreach ($records as $row) {
        // do here the huge chunk of math and
        // put in $data the results you need to display
    }
    $this->load->view('myview', $data)
}
```

**View**

```
<div> <?php echo $first_result; ?> </div>
<div> <?php echo $second_result; ?> </div>
```